# Visual studio 2010 project with per file custom build tools compiles one file at a time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I've got a project that used to work in VS 2008 that has a custom build tool for each file (runs a batch file) that used to work as expected.

On upgrading to VS 2010 when you build the project it only builds one of the source files, then stops without errors.

If I compile each file individually they work fine. If I repeatedly build the project it builds each source file in turn until they are all done.

I suspected the conversion process so re-created the project from scratch and it had the same issue..

any ideas?

Thanks

Trev

Comment: What's the return value from the batch file? I'd be surprised if that behaviour changed between versions but nothing else springs to mind. Could you redevelop the .bat as an msbuild task or similar?

Comment: The batch file just calls on to a couple of executeables I tried using specific exit codes from the batch file, if it is 0 I get current behaviour and 1 causes VStudio to report an error. I will look into trying an msbuild task instead (thanks for the idea). It's most odd.

Comment: Seems as though it is just that batch files don't work as per file custom build tools. Even if they just echo out the filename. After your comment I just tried replicating the contents of the batch file in the command window with some minor adjustments and all worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is by design in Visual Studio 2010:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572435/only-1-custom-build-step-is-executed-in-a-build

There is a little more discussion here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/3de31464-46fb-40a3-a666-496355b1b6be/

I'd love to have a work around for this.

Comment: looked at the first link and it seemed to suggest if you use "call mybatch.bat" it will work - I'll give that a try. Thanks for the pointers. Will update when I know if it works..